# How can I filter out Duplicated Rows per Group

Tags: r, dplyr

So this is the data I'm working with:

```
ID    Year    State    Grade    Loss    Total    
1     2016    AZ       A        50      1000
1     2016    AZ       A        50      1000
2     2016    AZ       B        0       5000
3     2017    AZ       A        0       2000
4     2017    AZ       C        10      100
2     2017    AZ       B        0       3000
```

What I'm trying to do is create a table that shows the amount of value lost that is grouped by Year, State and Grade. That part I have done but the issue is you can see that there is a duplicated row for ID=1. I need to add a component to my code that removes any duplicated rows like it in my data once I have grouped the data by Year, State and Grade.

The reason I want to remove the duplicates after I have grouped the data is that the ID number may duplicate for a different year but that is OK as that is a new observation. I just want to remove any duplicates if the Year, State and Grade match. Basically if the whole row is a duplicate, it should be removed.

I can't tell if I should use Unique() or Distinct() but here is what I have so far:

```
   Answer <- data %>%
        group_by(Year, State, Grade) %>%
        filter(row_number(ID) == 1) %>% #This is the part to replace
        summarise(x = sum(Loss) / sum(Total)) %>%
        spread(State, x)
```

The output should look like this:

```
Year    State    Grade    x
2016    AZ       A        0.05
2016    AZ       B        0
2016    AZ       C        0
2017    AZ       A        0
2017    AZ       B        0
2017    AZ       C        0.1
```

Comment: Did you meant to remove all the duplicate elements or just keep the unique values

Comment: Remove the duplicated rows. They are skewing the final value for X as the same value is being included in the summation when it should not be.

Comment: Can you show the calculation to get the `0.00833`

Comment: go with `distinct() ` you can re-check the output with `library(data.table);setDT(data)[,unique(.SD),.(Year, State, Grade)]
`

Comment: just add a `distinct()` line to your pipe to remove any rows that are duplicates across every column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things. Below, I use `distinct` to remove duplicate rows. Also, in your expected results you have an entry for grade C for 2016, which isn't in your original data. So, I used `complete` to add this (and any other missing cases) as a zero. Finally, as @akrun notes above: where does `0.00833` come from? Typo or have I misunderstood the calculation?

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID    Year    State    Grade    Loss    Total    
1     2016    AZ       A        50      1000
1     2016    AZ       A        50      1000
2     2016    AZ       B        0       5000
3     2017    AZ       A        0       2000
4     2017    AZ       C        10      100
2     2017    AZ       B        0       3000", header = TRUE)

Answer <- df %>%  
  distinct %>% 
  group_by(Year, State, Grade) %>%
  summarise(x = sum(Loss) / sum(Total)) %>%
  complete(Year, State, Grade, fill = list(x = 0)) 

# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# # Groups:   Year, State [2]
#    Year State Grade     x
#   <int> <fct> <fct> <dbl>
# 1  2016 AZ    A      0.05
# 2  2016 AZ    B      0   
# 3  2016 AZ    C      0   
# 4  2017 AZ    A      0   
# 5  2017 AZ    B      0   
# 6  2017 AZ    C      0.1
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, X should be 0.05. The calculation for 0.05 comes from adding up all the values for Loss and Total that match the criteria of each group. Thus for any rows that match the conditions (2016, AZ, A), X = 50/(1000+5000) = 0.05. My original issue is that the duplicated rows are being include in this formula which skews the final result.

Comment: Also, don't worry about the missing C. The spread() function takes care of that and returns a Null value if the C is missing which is fine.